# Efeito de paginação

Tags: javascript, css

Observe sites e blogs com paginação no cabeçalho ou rodapé. Quando acionado o Botão `Anterior` ou `Próximo`, é realçado em **negrito** o link númerico, sinalizando a página onde o usuário está no momento.

Bem, em meio a visualização desta funcionalidade, surgiu a dúvida:

Como conseguir este efeito sinalizar link de paginação a cada clique em um dos botões de controle(Anterior/Próximo), ou seja, destacar o link da página no qual o usuário está no momento.

## Exemplo

O usuário visita a Página Home, e a mesma esta setada como [1] na barra de paginação.

Em seguida, o Usuário desliza o ponteiro do mouse até a barra de paginação ..

`<< Voltar [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Avançar >>`

.. e clica no botão `Avançar` .. logo é redirecionado outra página, e na barra de paginação é sinalizado [2] ..

`<< Voltar 1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Avançar >>`

.. ele prossegue e clica no botão `Avançar` novamente .. e tão logo é direcionado outra página e agora é sinalizado o link [3] ..

`<< Voltar 1 2 [3] 4 5 6 7 8 9 Avançar >>`

> Isso mesmo ir alternando de número da paginação a cada clique nos botões de controle `Voltar`/`Avançar`.

Comment: Os dados da próxima página estão no servidor ou os dados de todas as páginas já foram baixados para o cliente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, a forma mais conveniente depende do seu ambiente. Isso geralmente é feito server-side, mas como você marcou javascript e css vou apresentar uma maneira de fazer com essas tecnologias.

Quando a pessoa clicar em **próximo**, basta verificar qual o número da página atualmente está selecionado, de-selecionar essa número, incrementá-lo e selecionar o número incrementado. Quando a pessoa clicar em **anterior** o raciocínio é semelhante, basta decrementar ao invés de incrementar.

Um exemplo rápido disso seria esse código:

```js
document.getElementById('avancar').onclick = function() { mudaPagina(1) };
document.getElementById('voltar').onclick = function() { mudaPagina(-1) };

function mudaPagina(cont) {
  // Obtém elemento da página atual
  var pagAtual = document.getElementsByClassName('selecionado')[0];
  
  // Deseleciona a nova página
  pagAtual.className = '';
  
  // Obtém o número da nova página
  var numNovaPagina = parseInt(pagAtual.innerText) + cont;
  
  // Seleciona a nova página
  var novaPagina = document.getElementById('p' + numNovaPagina);
  novaPagina.className = 'selecionado';
  
  // Desabilita voltar/avançar se estiver nos limites
  var limiteEsquerda = document.getElementById('p' + (numNovaPagina - 1)) == null;
  document.getElementById('voltar').disabled = limiteEsquerda;

  var limiteDireita = document.getElementById('p' + (numNovaPagina + 1)) == null;
    document.getElementById('avancar').disabled = limiteDireita;
}
```

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline; color: blue; cursor: pointer; padding: 3px;
}
span.selecionado {
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="voltar" value="<< Voltar">
<span id="p1">1</span>
<span id="p2" class="selecionado">2</span>
<span id="p3">3</span>
<span id="p4">4</span>
<button id="avancar">Avançar >></button>
```

Apesar de ser simples fazer isso, existem muitas bibliotecas prontas que já vem com vários recursos adicionais. O nome desse tipo de componente é **paginator**, você pode [conferir uma lista com 10 deles em JQuery](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/) ou buscar outras alternativas.

Comment: Originalmente usava classList e querySelector, que são APIs elegantes mas não funcionam em navegadores obsoletos. Substituí por métodos mais amplamente compatíveis.

Comment: boa resposta @rodorgas mas a pessoa usar um framework so para fazer isso ai ja e demais +1

Comment: @Assanges a minha implementação é só o básico, falta controle dos elementos a serem exibidos em cada página, elipsar o controle quando há mais páginas que o viewport, suporte a mobile... Programação tem tudo a ver com reusabilidade: faz mais sentido gastar energia em ideias novas, não em problemas que todo mundo continua resolvendo de novo e de novo nos últimos 10 anos.

Answer (score 0):

Ainda com a resposta de **@rodorgas** tive uma certa decepção num determinado navegador(não funcionou), então resolvi pesquisar mais um pouco, à saber como poderia desenvolver um script flexível, para todos navegadores.

Como **@rodorgas** mencionou:

*"Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, a forma mais conveniente depende do seu ambiente".*

A solução encontrada foi, **recriar** este ***Efeito Paginação***. Confira:

#Código

```js
/* Rotina Do Botão Próximo */

document.getElementById('menos').disabled=true;

el = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

var contar = 0;  

var element_2 = document.getElementById('mais');

element_2.onclick = function() {  

contar++;

if (contar == 1) {  
    el[0].className = '';
    el[contar].className = 'selecionado';
    document.getElementById('menos').disabled = false;
}
else if (contar == 2) {
    el[1].className = '';
    el[contar].className = 'selecionado';
}
else if (contar == 3) {
    el[2].className = '';
    el[contar].className = 'selecionado';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('mais').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('menos').disabled=false;
}
};



/* Rotina Do Botão Anterior */

var element_1 = document.getElementById('menos');

element_1.onclick = function() {  

contar--;

if (contar == 1) {  
    el[0].className = 'selecionado';
    el[contar].className = '';
    document.getElementById('mais').disabled = false;
}
else if (contar == 2) {
   el[1].className = 'selecionado';
   el[contar].className = '';
}
else if (contar == 3) {
   el[2].className = 'selecionado';
   el[contar].className = '';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('menos').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('mais').disabled=false;
}
};
```

```css
span {
   cursor: pointer; padding: 3px;
}
span.selecionado {
   font-weight: bolder;
   background-color: #333;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<center>

<input type="button" id="menos" value="&#171 Anterior"/>

<span class="selecionado">1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>

<input type="button" id="mais" value="Próximo &#187"/>

</center>
```

> **DICAS**
>
> Este **Efeito Paginação** cai muito bem, com: **Ancoras, Array, Strings, Iframe, Table, links,** etc...
>
> Outra coisa é, você mesmo pode definir um diretório para conter todas as páginas a serem redirecionados, via paginação, vale dizer que para melhor organização deverão estar nomeadas de A - Z ou ordenadas por números, assim fica mais fácil fazer a programação manual.
>
> **IMPORTANTE!**
>
> As **Dicas** bem como **Efeito Paginação** dada aqui, aplica-se somente para o uso com Javascript, não havendo vínculo algum com linguagem PHP, não tem nada haver em deixar o controle da paginação por conta do Servidor, mas sim criar uma programação obstrusivo(Quando ha Javascript Habilitado no Navegador).
>
> Agora, é só deixar a criatividade solta.

Para dar um visual profissional basta substituir o CSS do código acima pelo do tutorial [Paginação estilo Digg com CSS](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2007/03/07/paginacao-estilo-digg-com-css/) que ilustra de modo simples, a criação da barra de paginação. 

Ha também um bom tutorial de [Efeito Paginação em CSS3](http://www.betomarques.com/artigos/artigo_011.php)